# How to share context between multiple libraries?

Tags: reactjs, shared-libraries, react-context

I'm working on a monorepo with a collection of frontend libraries and looking to use a context from one library in another library that would both be used in the same app.

For example, we have library "a", which contains the context `ContextA` that is used by some components (call one of them `<ComponentA>`), and some of the components in library "b" use `ContextA` as well (call one of them `<ComponentB>`).

In an application, the components in library "b" are not able to find a provider for `ContextA`. I believe this is because when the libraries are built and minified, the final variable name for `ContextA` is different in each build file. I could be wrong on that though, it could also have something to do with scoping.

Is there a way to share context between two libraries?

If the issue is just with minification, is there a way to control the final names just for contexts so they stay the same across libraries? (Using rollup with babel plugin by the way)

---

**Additional information**:

My naive approach was just to use a provider for `ContextA` in the app that both `<ComponentA>` and `<ComponentB>` could use.

For example (in the application):

```
function App() {
    return (
        <ContextA.Provider value={100}>
            <ComponentA/>
            <ComponentB/>
        </ContextA.Provider>
    )
}
```

However, as mentioned above, I found that the components in library "b" were not able to find the provider for `ContextA`.

So I turned to a new approach using a dependent context manager that just receives a context value and renders a provider of that context in library "b" so that the components in library "b" can find the context. Like this (in the application):

```
function App() {
    return (
        <ContextA.Provider value={100}>
            <BContextManager>
                <ComponentA/>
                <ComponentB/>
            </BContextManager>
        </ContextA.Provider>
    )
}

function BContextManager({children}) {
    const contextValue = React.useContext(ContextA);
    return (
        <DependentContextManagerB contextValue={contextValue}>
            {children}
        </DependentContextManagerB>
    )
}
```

Where `<DependentContextManagerB>` would look like this (defined in library "b"):

```
function DependentContextManagerB({contextValue, children}) {
    return (
        <ContextA.Provider value={contextValue}>
            {children}
        </ContextA.Provider>
    )
}
```

This approach works with global contexts (those with a single provider for the whole app), if a bit clunky. However this approach is too clunky to be feasible with more local contexts (ones where there may be many providers throughout the app).

---

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993563/how-to-share-context-between-different-component-libraries-in-react), which seems to be about creating a provider for a context from a library in an application (only deals with one library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a relevant issue on React's issues page: [Bug: React Context API is not working from custom NPM library](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18731)

Resolution is to move "b"'s dependency on "a" to a peer dependency (same way React is usually included so that only one instance of React is present).

So if `b/package.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "b",
    "dependencies": {
        "a": "^0.0.0"
    }
}
```

update it to this:

```
{
    "name": "b",
    "peerDependencies": {
        "a": "^0.0.0"
    }
}
```

---

This has the additional benefit of reducing the bundle size for library "b" (in my case fairly significantly: 12% decrease) and the final build size of the application (less significantly but there's basically 30 lines of code in my test app).